# who send sighup signal to childs when session leader exit, the c library or kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

As I know from `man 3 exit` :

> If  the  exiting process is a session leader and its controlling
> terminal is the controlling terminal of the session, then each process
> in the foreground process group of this controlling terminal is sent a
> SIGHUP signal

but who send the signal? it's c library or kernel ?

what clean work, c library do, and what clean work kernel do.

Answer (score 2):

It's the kernel which sends the `SIGHUP` signal to the foreground process group when the controlling process (i.e. a session leader with a controlling terminal) exits -- see [`disassociate_ctty()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/tty_jobctrl.c#L232) which is called from `do_exit()`.

I have no idea if job control could be implemented *at all* in userland, even theoretically -- FWIW it's in the kernel in all the implementations I know of.

However, notice that many shells (like bash) supplement the job control interface implemented by the operating system with their own non-standard quirks and features, making people wrongly assume that they're part of the same interface.